# Convert financial function from vb.net to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this line of code in VB.net:

```
 PrincipalPayment = System.Math.Ceiling(FormatNumber(-PPmt(lRate / 1200, i, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance), 3) * 100) / 100
```

I need to convert it to C# so I converted like this and included

```
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

PrincipalPayment = System.Math.Ceiling(
    Convert.ToDouble((Convert.ToInt32(
        Strings.FormatNumber(
            -Financial.PPmt(lRate / 1200, i, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance), 3)) * 100) / 100));
```

but I am getting this error:

> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: You could use a debugger and step through your code.

Comment: Convert.ToDouble, Convert.ToInt32?  Just use a [Code Converter](http://converter.telerik.com/).  But that error is hinting at something else.

Comment: It's financial, so I'd highly recommend using `decimal` instead of `float` or `double`.

Comment: I have uses online converter but it had some syntax error so I had to convert. Also I debug and I get this error exactly I this line when I debug.

Comment: @Eris Can't convert to decimal as PrincipalPayment  is already double.

Comment: Clearly the VB code was crap in the first place if it's taking a `Double`, formatting it as a `String` and then taking the `Ceiling` of that.  `PPmt` returns a `Double` so you should not be converting that to a `String` at all.

Comment: Nothing to do with the original question... I don't code in VB.Net but I'm frequently surprised and sometimes impressed by the weird and wonderful classes hidden in it that MS never bothered to reintroduce in .Net FW / C# :)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try and understand what the original code does by pulling the nested expression apart:

```
rppmt = PPmt(lRate / 1200, i, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance)
rfnum = FormatNumber(-rppmt, 3)
PrincipalPayment = System.Math.Ceiling(rfnum * 100) / 100
```

According to MSDN, PPmt() takes a bunch of doubles, and returns a double; FormatNumber() takes an epression (object) and the number of digits after the decimal point (int), and returns a string; Ceiling() will take a double, and return a double.

That should be enough information to know which type casts to employ where; C# can probably do most of them implicitly. You use Convert.ToInt32() but I believe it is out of place; the following should be enough:

```
double PrincipalPayment(int lRate, int i, int lTerm, double lStartLoanBalance)
{
    var rppmt = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.PPmt(lRate / 1200, i, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance);
    var rfnum = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(-rppmt, 3);
    return System.Math.Ceiling(Double.Parse(rfnum) * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Whether this can be improved upon, I leave as an exercise to others. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
public static double PrincipalPayment(double lRate, int i, int lTerm, double lStartLoanBalance)
{
     var rppmt = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Financial.PPmt(lRate / 1200, i, lTerm, lStartLoanBalance);
     var rfnum = Microsoft.VisualBasic.Strings.FormatNumber(-rppmt, 3);
     return System.Math.Ceiling(Double.Parse(rfnum) * 100.0) / 100.0;
}
```

Comment: Once formatted, your code seems to be an exact duplicate of the answer of @dumetrulo...